# HTTP issue for post request in Angular JS with Cordova and jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, cordova, http

I have issues in my angular JavaScript web service using $http Angular .

The above same web service gave a correct response  when I am using the same web service using jQuery AJAX, but when I used the same service using $http Angular JS, it causes an error.

Angular JS $http Code:

```
mainApp.controller('registrationCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
  $scope.registration=function(){
     console.log("registration called");

        var regEmail=$("#regEmail").val();
        var regPass=$("#passEmail").val();
       var ws_url="http://apparelinindia.com/selfiestandoff/WebServices/register";
       var data={user_email:regEmail, user_password:regPass}
       var request = $http.post(ws_url, data).then(function(response){

           console.log(response);

       }, function(response){
            console.log("error"+response);
       });


      };
});
```

jQuery AJAX Code:

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "http://apparelinindia.com/selfiestandoff/WebServices/register",
           data:{user_email:reg_useremail, user_password:reg_userpass},    
           dataType: "json",
           headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
           crossDomain: true,
           cache:false,
           beforeSend: function (){ 
             app.showBlur();

          },
            success: function(resData){
            var resObj =resData;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(resObj));
         },
            complete: function (){
         },
           error:function(x, t, m){

           },
     });
```

please find my console details...

```
registration called
services.js:64 Object {data: Object, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}config: Objectdata: Objecterror: Objectcode: "103"message: "Required Parameters not found"__proto__: Objectstatus: false__proto__: Objectheaders: (c)status: 200statusText: "OK"__proto__: Object
```

Comment: What kind of error does it return? Please edit your question to include that.

Comment: in $http Angular error 103 required parameters not found... but with the same web service with $.ajax it gave the success response that is user is successfully registered.

Comment: Thanks! Please edit your question to include that information. Your question should contain all relevant information, so that people who might be able to help you doesn't have to read through the comments to find the pieces.

Comment: does those regEmail & regPass have values.. Instead of jQuery code.you should use `ng-model` so that those value will directly fetched from `$scope`

Comment: yes it is a textfield values. and i already used a $scope.email, $scope.password. but still the same issues are raised.

Comment: If $http gave a correct response i.e. user successful registered, please help me out.

Comment: please find my $http ws console... and can anyone implement in his end and tell me why it happened with $http but not with $.ajax...

Comment: Please provide me a solution if anyone found a solution. for the same issues.